# How to read and open gal file from a selected path in my pc?

Tags: python, pandas, file, gal

I used python code to analyse my data. But when I wanted to read the gal file I got error.

```
w = pd.read_gal("C:\\Users\\Yousif\\Downloads\\PythonSpatial\\statess7.gal")
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 
>   ----> 2 w = pd.read("C:\Users\Yousif\Downloads\PythonSpatial\statess7.gal")
>         3
>
> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read'

Also  once I used this function

```
w = pysal.open(pysal.examples.get_path("statess7.gal")).read()
```

I got this error

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 
>   ----> 2 w = pysal.open(pysal.examples.get_path("statess7.gal")).read()
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysal\examples__init__.py in
>   get_path(example_name)
>        33         return os.path.join(base, 'examples', example_name)
>        34     else:
>   ---> 35         raise KeyError(example_name + ' not found in PySAL built-in examples.')
>        36 
>        37
>
> KeyError: 'statess7.gal not found in PySAL built-in examples.'

I hope to find out how I can read and open gal file from path in my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

.gal are tab delimited, so could just try:

```
w = pd.read_table("C:\Users\Yousif\Downloads\PythonSpatial\statess7.gal")
```

(does pandas have a `.read_gal` method? I couldn't find it in the offical docs)

Edit: The above worked for me, but i had to set the encoding to get a readable dataframe,

```
df = pd.read_table("C:\path\file.gal", encoding="iso-8859-1")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mr. Yobmob. I have used your code but I got an error too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mr. Yobmob. I have used your code but I got an error too.  I have created classic Markov matrix in python. How can we create Spatial Markov matrix in python? I used the cod of Pysal library in python. check it, please.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this as well. I can read the .gal files provided in the pysal examples using    w = libpysal.io.open(libpysal.examples.get_path("Baltim_q.gal")).read()    So i tried pasting a .gal file created in GeoDa into the pysal examples directory, but i get     TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType.   The .gal from GeoDa is the same data type as the pysal example but for some reason it still kicks an error. Confusing.